# Why my flag hang there for a long time?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

I do a lot of review, and may make flags to the posts which match the flagging cases.

But when I check for the history, I found that there still some flagging request still stay not deemed. And that cases don't appear consecutive.
[image: The review tip image]

---

So I want to know about:

1. Will the flag being reviewed in order?
2. Will the flag be hanged there forever?
3. If there will be no longer review for the flag, will it be deleted?

Comment: We're having an oldest active flag contest? [August 12, 2013](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aADnr.png)

Comment: @MichaelT OH? What's that?

Comment: @MichaelT. Fantastic sir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No
2. No
3. Yes

...But, it could take a *very* long time for anything to happen to that flag.

#### See: [Do flags to close expire like votes to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207179/do-flags-to-close-expire-like-votes-to-close)

Comment: Based on what I've been hearing on meta in the past few months, this whole flag thing doesn't seem very scalable. Electing and keeping track of a gazillion moderators doesn't seem scalable either. Has anyone ever considered a sort of "intermediate moderator" that sits somewhere between 20k and moderator that has the power to do moderation tasks that doesn't require the sort of confidential access that current moderators have? tl;dr hierarchical moderation.

Comment: I'm also wondering about the first question, will the flag review dequeued in the flagging time from earliest to latest after filtering by the moderators?

Comment: @Mystical I'd go with deputized moderators; people who are deputized from the current batch of moderators.  The deputies could serve a year; and then cycle through.  It would be open to anyone over 20K in reputation.

Comment: @Mysticial: yes. The gold-badge closing privileges are sorta the "toe in the water" there. That said... Close flags aren't even shown to moderators anymore - they're used to drive the close queue, and that's all. If no one with close privileges cares about a flagged question, it'll just sit there regardless of what the moderators are doing.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the flag you're showing in your question is a closing flag* these flags just dump the question into the close vote review queue and are reviewed by other users with more than 3k rep.

There are currently 11.3k questions waiting to be reviewed in the close vote queue, so it may take a long time for anyone to see it.

I think Shog9 answered your other concerns *thoroughly*, just wanted to expand on why it takes so long.

*<sub>Not sure if this is the best term, but it'll do for now...</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I've notice that, all long-time-pending flags are close flags, but I'm also found that many same type close flags I raised had been reviewed. So I have this question.

Comment: @fish_ball It takes 5 close votes to close a question, some reach that faster than others simply by being seen by more people with more than 3k rep.

Comment: You say the post with more flag was shown prior to the other?

Comment: @fish_ball It's not only close flags that can take a while. For example, I raised a flag when a user started making a series of bad edits a month ago, and the flag is still active.